# Is it still true that there is no need in x64 version if the app is stand-alone and won't benefit from being 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008-r2, wow64

Since Windows Server 2008 R2, [WoW64 is an optional feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be uninstalled. It means that it is possible to have **64-bit only** server, that cannot execute 32-bit code. I'm trying to think about any possible benefit from disabling/uninstalling WoW64, apart from the two obvious ones: savings of disk space and lesser "attack surface" for malware (most is 32-bit), and I don't see any, while the drawback is huge: no 32-bit code is able to run there.

**My question:**
Is there anywhere any meaningful statistics/reports or at least anecdotal evidence that says how many "64-bit only" servers are out there, used in production? Is it time to start building 64-bit versions of software even if there is no benefit for the software itself being 64-bit just so it can run on these 64-bit only servers?

**Clarification:**
My software is a network bandwidth monitor which is used mainly on PCs, not servers, but some do use it on servers. It is hard to get any meaningful data from my clients on this subject since it's many clients that buy 1 copy and not few that buy a site license.

Comment: Questions about configuring your Win2008R2 server belong on ServerFault -- that's what it's there for.  Not just the "how?" but also the "why?".  Statistics questions on how many people use what server configuration should also fit nicely there.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't have any servers. As a developer I must decide whether these "64-bit only" servers are worth targeting (developer's effort for 64-bit version) or not.

Comment: Typically, WoW64 is disabled to reduce attack surface. (The relatively small disk space savings is rarely an issue on servers.) To determine whether your customers are the sorts of people who would disable WoW64 for security purposes, you should, um, go talk to your customers and find out. You didn't say what sort of software you're writing, so it's hard to say anything more specific. Maybe the people who use your software use it to manage X, and X is 32-bit only, in which case the answer is "Don't worry, WoW64 will be enabled, or they couldn't even run X."

Comment: Another potential benefit is that it might further reduce the number of security updates you need to install.  As a server admin, any month when none of the new updates are applicable to me is a good month.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks. I added a clarification to my question. If I could, I would certainly get this answer from my clients. However, I'm also concerned about a *prospective* client that is not interested in my software because there is no native 64-bit application available.

Comment: @haimg: A question being of interest to programmers doesn't automatically make it on topic.  This question is about server administration (even though you aren't doing it yourself), not about programming.

Comment: Well, then you answered your own question. You asked your customer, and they said "We want a 64-bit version."